# Scroll me da valores diferentes

Tags: jquery

```
function scrolEnId(id) {
        var plF = $('#playlist_final').height() / 1.7;
        console.log($('#pl_'+id).offset().top, plF);
        $('#playlist_final').animate({
            scrollTop: ($('#pl_'+id).offset().top - plF)
        }, 1500);
    }
    $(document).on('click',"li.item.sel",function () {
        $("li.item.rep").removeClass("rep");
        $(this).removeClass("sel");
        $(this).addClass("rep");
        var scroll = parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace("pl_",""));
        scrolEnId(scroll);
        console.log(scroll);
    });
    scrolEnId(65);
    console.log(65);
```

*Resultado de la consola*
slider.js:147 2972 321.7647058823529 
slider.js:161 65 (es el primer console.log con el id en la variable)
slider.js:147 187 321.7647058823529
slider.js:158 65 (es el ultimo console.log)
**Como se ve el id introducido es el mismo pero con mucha diferencia de resultados**
**Alguien sabe por que ocurre esto?**

Answer (score 1):

```
function scrolEnId(id) {
        var realH = $('#playlist_final').prop("scrollHeight");
        var height = $('#playlist_final').height();
        var TotalIDs = $('#playlist_final > .item').length;
        var scrollTo = (id-1) * (realH/TotalIDs) - (height/2.65) - ((realH/TotalIDs)/2);
        $('#playlist_final').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTo
        }, 1500);
    }
```

Así he conseguido que funcione!
Si alguien ve algun fallo en el calculo...